# Affect property of any div when it is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to affect the `background-color` of any item on my page when it is clicked. How can i do this without using id names? I've tried using `this` as you can see below but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $(this).css({'background-color': 'blue'});
});
```

Any help always appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```js
$(document).click(function(event) {
    $(event.target).css({'background-color': 'blue'});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>DIV</div>
<span>SPAN</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not look at [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)?

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.target.style['background-color'] = 'blue';
});
```